# JNoSQL + MongoDB + Wildfly Swarm

Tags: java, mongodb, wildfly-swarm, jnosql

I was trying to create a [hello world with JNoSQL](https://github.com/vepo/wildly-swarm-jnosql), Mongo and Wildfly Swarm.

The use `@Inject` of `DocumentCollectionManager` is working, but it is not working with a `Repository`.

This is how I'm injecting:

```
@Inject
private DocumentCollectionManager entityManager; // works

@Inject
@Database(DatabaseType.DOCUMENT)
private UserRepository userRepository; // do not work!
```

This is how I configured the producer:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MongoProducer {
    private static final String DATABASE = "db";

    @Inject
    @ConfigurationUnit(name = "document", fileName = "jnosql.yaml")
    private DocumentCollectionManagerFactory<MongoDBDocumentCollectionManager> entityManager;

    @Produces
    @Database(DatabaseType.DOCUMENT)
    public DocumentCollectionManager getManager() {
        return entityManager.get(DATABASE);
    }

}
```

What can I do to automatic inject Repositories in my Wildfly Swarm application?

The throwed error:

```
2018-05-23 11:30:31,270 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."demo.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."demo.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1978)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type UserRepository with qualifiers @Database
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Database private com.example.demo.rest.HelloWorldEndpoint.userRepository
  at com.example.demo.rest.HelloWorldEndpoint.userRepository(HelloWorldEndpoint.java:0)

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:362)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:284)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:158)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:501)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:61)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:59)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)

2018-05-23 11:30:31,278 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (main) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: (("deployment" => "demo.war")) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"demo.war\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type UserRepository with qualifiers @Database
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Database private com.example.demo.rest.HelloWorldEndpoint.userRepository
  at com.example.demo.rest.HelloWorldEndpoint.userRepository(HelloWorldEndpoint.java:0)
"}}
2018-05-23 11:30:31,279 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (main) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "demo.war" was rolled back with the following failure message:
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"demo.war\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type UserRepository with qualifiers @Database
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Database private com.example.demo.rest.HelloWorldEndpoint.userRepository
  at com.example.demo.rest.HelloWorldEndpoint.userRepository(HelloWorldEndpoint.java:0)
"}}
```

Comment: Can you raise an issue here http://issues.jboss.org/browse/THORN as it should be working

Comment: Created: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/THORN-2045

Comment: where this @ConfigurationUnit come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how is going?

There're same bugs in your code:

- The interface needs to be found by CDI, so I created a bean.xml to enable a full
  scan in your code. On the MongoProducer you
- don't need the: @Database(DatabaseType.DOCUMENT)

I created a PR:
https://github.com/vepo/wildly-swarm-jnosql/pull/1